# How do I build a n-attribute recommendation system in Ruby

Tags: ruby, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, recommendation-engine

I'm thinking about building a recommendation system in Ruby that accepts 8 attributes, the system will look at sample's matrix and then give recommendations based on the sample data. How do I do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Well sorry to break it to you, but ruby is not designed for such tasks.. it is not recommended to do number crunching tasks in this language. Best you can do is may be integrate some third party api or get some native gem to do it for your.. Here is a [link](https://github.com/josephmisiti/awesome-machine-learning#ruby-general-purpose) to some of the interesting gems available to you.. This is gonna be very slow..

Comment: “How do I do this?”—You code.

Comment: Start by learning how to use a matrix in Ruby  http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html